# Workflow error in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

i m trying to run an example of microsoft workflow software. I get the following error in a line:

```
wsh.Description.Behaviors.Add(new SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreBehavior(ApprovalProcessDBConnectionString));
        WorkflowIdleBehavior wib = new WorkflowIdleBehavior();
        wib.TimeToUnload = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        wsh.Description.Behaviors.Add(wib);

        wsh.Open(); <-- error: The InstanceStore could not be initialized.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: C? With `new`? I think not. tag changed to c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to run a couple of queries to set up an InstanceStore in your database.

Look for:

```
SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema.sql
SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreLogic.sql
```

in the folder:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.xxx\SQL\EN
```

Just run those two queries on whatever database you're connecting to via your ApprovalProcessDBConnectionString.